# React.js toggle hide-show display problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to React toggle show-hide and ran into a problem.

I called my array with the map function. then I did the open-hide situations with the toggle function but the problem starts here. As soon as I click on any item, the whole array show and hide.

What am I doing wrong here? I just want to see the hide-show status of the item I clicked but all of them are listed.

[image]

My code:

```
export default function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const toggleHandler = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {example.map((item) => (
        <>
          <div onClick={toggleHandler}>
            <p style={{ margin: 0, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
              {`${item.year} - Total: `} <span>{item.price}</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          {show ? <div>{item.monthlyInstallment}</div> : ""}
        </>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

My example file: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-example-ky5sn?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: did you checked https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys @ogulcan

Comment: Once you set `show` to `true`, on the next render for all items show will be `true` and therefore you see all items. You need to narrow down your show logic.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the state boolean is common for all the items.

You can create an item component that has its own local `show` state.

If you don't want to create a child component you can use a map who's key would be item `id` as the state and value would be the boolean `show`

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-example-forked-ijt82?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

You use the same show value for all your items. When it sets the value true for one, it changes for all.

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly modified your [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/toggle-example-forked-nimxh?file=/src/App.js:517-1082) to have `<List />` a separate Component that has it's own `show/hide` state

```
const List = (item) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const toggleHandler = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={toggleHandler}>
         <p style={{ margin: 0, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          {`${item.year} - Total: `} <span>{item.price}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
      {show ? <div>{item.monthlyInstallment}</div> : ""}
    </>
   );
 };


export default function App() {
 return (
   <div className="App">
     {example.map((item) => (<List key={item.id} {...item} />))}
   </div>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the `show` state is used by every item on the array, what you can do is have a show state for each item, this can be done in many ways, but the cleanest would be to separate the item on its own component and give it its own state.

```
const Item = ({ item }) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const toggleHandler = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return 
        <>
          <div onClick={toggleHandler}>
            <p style={{ margin: 0, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
              {`${item.year} - Total: `} <span>{item.price}</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          {show ? <div>{item.monthlyInstallment}</div> : ""}
        </>
} 

export default function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {example.map((item) => <Item item={item} />)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have one state which can contain only `true` or `false`, so React can't know which item or your list is show.

A solution is to create a component which is rendered for each "item" :

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {example.map((item) => (
        <Test key={item.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

function Test({ item }) {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const toggleHandler = () => {
    setShow(!show);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div onClick={toggleHandler}>
        <p style={{ margin: 0, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
          {`${item.year} - Total: `} <span>{item.price}</span>
        </p>
      </div>

      {show ? <div>{item.monthlyInstallment}</div> : ""}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you set `show` to `true`, on the next render for all items `show` will be `true` and therefore you see all items. You need to narrow down your show logic.

What you can do as a fix is:

1. Pass the `id` of the item being clicked to `togglerHandler`.
2. If `show` is not already equal to the passed `id`, set `show` to the passed `id`.
3. If `show` is already equal to the passed `id`, set `show` to `null`.
4. Now while rendering `monthlyInstallment` just check if `show === item.id`, if it is display the `div` else don't.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const example = [
  {
    id: "1",
    year: "2021",
    price: 300,
    monthlyInstallment: 582.5
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    year: 2022,
    price: 400,
    monthlyInstallment: 500.5
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    year: "2023",
    price: 500,
    monthlyInstallment: 421.5
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    year: "2024",
    price: 600,
    monthlyInstallment: 365.5
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    year: "2025",
    price: "700$",
    monthlyInstallment: 312.5
  }
];

function App() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(null);
  const toggleHandler = (id) => {
    (id === show) ? setShow(null): setShow(id)
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {example.map((item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>
          <div onClick={() => toggleHandler(item.id)}>
            <p style={{ margin: 0, fontWeight: "bold" }}>
              {`${item.year} - Total: `} <span>{item.price}</span>
            </p>
          </div>
          {show === item.id ? <div>{item.monthlyInstallment}</div> : ""}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ogulcan Please check if this solves your problem, do let me know if you have any issues.